# Error when opening a file in Excel but opens fine in Open XML SDK

Tags: xml, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I created a test file, containing just one string on column `A1`.
When I open the file in Excel it show's an error message:

> **filex.xml contains unreadable content**

When I click on `Yes` to try recover the file, I get the following messages (translated):

> **Some parts of this workshteets were recovered or deleted**
>
> **Deleted records: Celinformation from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml**

So the string value in column `A1` was removed.

When I open the file in *Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office* and click `validate`, I get no errors.

How can I fix this?

The file can be downloaded at: [file.xml](http://bit.ly/17frBEh)

Comment: Have you tried comparing a file set up with the same info that you produce, but saved directly from excel?

Comment: Yes I did. Only some warnings showed, time differences and stuff. The rest was exactly the same.

Comment: Some differences make all the difference in OpenXML.

Comment: Problem solved.
/xl/sharedStrings had an appliction/xml content type in stead of application/vnd.openxmlformats

Comment: @WebDevver good that your problem is solved please add it as answer and accept it